# jQuery: select all elements of a given class on hover, except for this

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have ten elements on a page with the same class.

When I hover over one of them I want to alter the other nine.

Here's what I have so far...

```
$("*[class='myClass']:not(this)").css({"top":"10px"});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that it selects all elements including the one being hovered...

Comment: whay `*[class='myClass']`? Simple using `.myClass` is cleaner and safer (in case you have other classes set for the element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either this:

```
$(".myClass:not(:hover)")
```

or this:

```
$(".myClass").not(":hover")
```

or this:

```
$(".myClass").not(this)
```

The last one assumes you're inside a `mouseover` or `mousenter` (or `hover`) event handler. I also believe you have to reset the style on mouseout. Working demonstation: http://jsfiddle.net/tt8cz/

Answer (score 4):

Using the attribute selector to select by class is a little redundant (not to mention slow) as there is a class selector. Try this:

```
$(".myClass").mouseover(function() {
    $('.myClass').not(this).css({"top":"10px"});
});
```

If you want to reset the effect on mouseout, use `hover()` with two function parameters. Also, it's better in this case to use a class.

```
$(".myClass").hover(function() {
    $('.myClass').not(this).addClass('foo');
},
function() {
     $('.myClass').not(this).removeClass('foo');
});
```

```css
.foo { top: 10px; }
```

Comment: Note that `[class='myClass']` and `.myClass` are different. Most probably the OP refers to the second one and didn't know how its done.

Comment: @Diego True, my assumption was that as you say the OP is looking for any element with `.myClass`, not an element which **only** has `.myClass`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.not` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

> Remove elements from the set of matched elements

```
$("*[class='myClass']").not(this).css({"top":"10px"});
```

Comment: @Aesthete: Sure, but the OP isn't using the class selector either. I, too, tend to keep the code in my answers as close to the OP's code to avoid lengthy comments back and forth to explain why you changed some things

Comment: @Aesthete: The exact answer was posted 2 secs before mine.. Couldn't know. Also I added the link to jQuery docs and its description of the method. The selector `$("*[class='myClass']")` was copied from the question. Maybe he wants exactly that and not `.myClass`. They are different things I can't know which one is correct in his context. You shouldn't downvote!!

Comment: @Diego - Edit your answer a little so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: @Diego: you know I agree with you, but please let it go. Ppl will DV, sometimes rightly so, sometimes just because they're in a bad mood. Whatever reasons they have, that's their problem. Somewhere on meta.satckoverflow the answer of SO's admins to _"unfair"_ down-votes was: this is the internet, grow some balls :), anyway: I gave you +1, still makes for +8 rep ;)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, you are right.. Sometimes right and sometimes not. I just explained myself.

Comment: @Diego: I just reacted to the _You shoudln't downvote!!_ bit of your comment. IMO, ppl are free to down-vote even the best of answers. That just goes to show how childish they are :P. I've gotten down-votes because ppl found that the question, and with it my answer, didn't deserve that many upvotes. Silly, but then there is no cure for stupidity... ah well, this down-vote has gotten more attention than it deserves already, so let's leave it be. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.not` method, which accepts a jQuery object, too:

```
$('.myClass').not($(this)).css({"top":"10px"});
```

[The docs](http://api.jquery.com/not/) don't mention this possibility at first glance, but one of the first comments do

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with just CSS:

HTML:

```
<ol id="items">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ol>​
```

CSS:

```
#items:hover > li { padding-left:5px; }
#items:hover > li:hover { padding-left:0; }
```

I've used `padding-left`, but you can use any property ofcourse.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rS7ZR/1/)**.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to do, you can just change the style on all elements of `.myClass`, then change it back on `this`:

```
$('.myClass').hover(function() {
    $(".myClass").css({"background":"blue"});
    $(this).css({"background":"red"});
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hAMPA/

Or also handle the hover out state as Rory McCrossan suggested.

Comment: Hi... I'm sure this method works, but it's actually the approach you took in the comments to my question that I have used. Can't give that the tick though!

Comment: Okay, I added that as a separate answer. For some reason, that didn't work when I first tested, so I changed the approach when adding this answer...

Answer (score 0):

I made the next sample using background-color parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.myClass').live('mouseover',function(){
        var element = $(this);
        $(this).css({"background-color":"#FF0000"});
        $('.myClass').each(function(){
            if(element.html() != $(this).html()){
                $(this).css({"background-color":"#FFFFFF"});
            }
        });
    });
});
```